# vSOMEIP support on yocto

Tags: yocto

I am working on a component which is dependent on vSOMEIP, yocto dont have support 
for vSOMEIP, i am trying to add myself, to make this available to my component.
I created recipes-vSOMEIP recipe, and copied the sources.
My bb layer looks like this

```
SECTION = "devel"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://*"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit cmake

FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}"
```

---

The sources are getting compiled, but not able to install them.

Got Below error, which doing packaging

```
ERROR: vSOMEIP-1.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue: vSOMEIP: Files/directories were installed 
but not shipped in any package:
  /usr/etc

  /usr/lib/libvsomeip.so.2.2.4

  /usr/lib/libvsomeip-sd.so.2.2.4

  /usr/lib/libvsomeip.so.2

  /usr/lib/libvsomeip-sd.so.2

  /usr/lib/cmake

  /usr/lib/cmake/vsomeip

  /usr/lib/cmake/vsomeip/vsomeipTargets-noconfig.cmake

  /usr/lib/cmake/vsomeip/vsomeipConfig.cmake

  /usr/lib/cmake/vsomeip/vsomeipConfigVersion.cmake

  /usr/lib/cmake/vsomeip/vsomeipTargets.cmake

  /usr/etc/vsomeip

  /usr/etc/vsomeip/vsomeip-tcp-service.json

  /usr/etc/vsomeip/vsomeip-tcp-client.json

  /usr/etc/vsomeip/vsomeip-udp-client.json

  /usr/etc/vsomeip/vsomeip.json

  /usr/etc/vsomeip/vsomeip-udp-service.json

  /usr/etc/vsomeip/vsomeip-local.json

Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
vSOMEIP: 18 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
ERROR: vSOMEIP-1.0-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
ERROR: vSOMEIP-1.0-r0 do_package: Function failed: do_package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently seem just to install `/usr/bin` itself.
Try to add the other directories you need:

```
FILES_${PN} += " \
  ${bindir} \
  ${bindir}/* \
  ${libdir} \
  ${libdir}/* \
  ${sysconfdir} \
  ${sysconfdir}/vsomeip \
  ${sysconfdir}/vsomeip/*
  "
```

I also think that that everything under `/usr/lib/cmake` is not intended to be installed. You should remove it after installing by adding

```
do_install_append() {
  rm -rf ${D}${libdir}/cmake
}
```

to the recipe

---

**Update:** @Anders answer is probably right.

You should not set FILES_${PN} with `=`

If you need to alter it use `+=`.

In your case the variable should be correctly set by the cmake class you include with `inherit cmake`

So just remove `FILES_${PN}` and everything should still work.

Comment: No, the cmake directory should go out the `${PN}-dev` package. It should preferably not be deleted.

Comment: Yes you are right! cmake probably sets the variable right

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the line

```
FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}"
```

The default value for `FILES_${PN}` should suffice for you. Never rewrite that variable, unless you know what you're doing, rather append to it if needed.

Comment: Sure, i appended instead of directly initializing FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}"

Answer (score 1):

A ready recipe for vSomeIP is provided by Genivi Consortium. Please refer to [vSomeIP recipe](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-ivi/tree/meta-ivi/recipes-core-ivi/vsomeip/vsomeip_2.0.1.bb?h=master)